# Move virtualbox .vdi to physical disk but keep virtual-ness

Tags: virtualbox, migration, vdi

## Main Problem

I have a Win 10 Pro host with 5 hard drives. I am trying to move my .vdi virtual machine (Windows Server 2012 R2) onto a dedicated hard drive. I am guessing that I can easily just move the .vdi file to the extra drive and resize it to take the entire drive, but I read that you can directly use a raw disk with a .vdmk file to reference the raw disk.

I know how to move the .vdi. I know how to resize a .vdi. I know how to link a .vdmk to a raw disk.

I don't know for sure how to migrate the .vdi data to the raw disk. Maybe I could convert the .vdi to a .img then use a linux live cd to write to the spare disk with dd? Or does Virtualbox have some native utility to do all this in a more convenient way?

I'm not trying to migrate the entire VM to a whole new hardware system. Just trying to use one of my 5 real/physical/raw host hard drives instead of a virtual hard drive .vdi file.

P.S. I'm not afraid of the command line cmd.exe, Powershell, or BASh.

### Update 1

Dang. I ran VirtualBox as Administrater and attached the .vdi and .vmdk as SATA and GPARTED Live as IDE optical drive. Then did `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb` and the VM crashed with this error:

> An error has occurred during virtual machine execution! The error
>   details are shown below. You may try to correct the error and resume
>   the virtual machine execution.
>
> The I/O cache encountered an error while
>   updating data in medium "ahci-0-1" (rc=VERR_ACCESS_DENIED).
>   Make sure there is enough free space on the disk and that the disk is
>   working properly. Operation can be resumed afterwards.
>
> Error ID:BLKCACHE_IOERR 
>   Severity: Non-Fatal Error

When I rebooted the VM with GPARTED Live still attached, it appears that the dd operation actually started but finished part-way through:

[image: dd operation unfinished]

Well, the error message is indicating multiple potential issues:

1. Possible permission issues
2. Possible disk space issues

That's confusing to me since:

1. The .vmdk references a cleanly NTFS formatted 120GB SSD
2. The .vdi is theoretically 40GB with only 20GB used
3. I'm running dd with sudo
4. I'm running VirtualBox as Administrator

Comment: Why not just hook the VDI to a VM, hook the RAW disk to same VM, and then copy data?

Comment: Omg. How could I overlook something like this? I'll try to mount the vdi and raw disk like you said. Then mount GPARTED iso and use dd from there. Wow. I'll let you know how it works after I get back home. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Didn't work. Maybe I did it wrong. I updated the post. Any suggestions? - Maybe it didn't work because the .vdi is dynamically allocated?